# How do I get old activity window

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext, android-button

I will explain my problem on basic case. Assume I have 2 activities, A and B. They have 1 EditText and 1 Button both. Buttons are for navigate between activities. EditTexts are for holding the data. Assume EditTexts are filled in both activities, but when I click to any of the button, I don't want to lose data of EditTexts. I have method onClickListener() for buttons;

for button in A:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

for button in B:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(B.this, A.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But when I click buttons, EditTexts texts are disappearing. I need help for keeping the data. Thanks in advance for all replies.

Comment: Your code does not take you between Activities A and B when pressing the buttons. It is creating a new Activity on each button press and adding them to a growing stack.

Comment: How can I navigate between them?

Comment: See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to flip back and forth between the 2 activities, you can do the following:

When you want to go from `A` to `B`, do this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will take an existing instance of `B` and rearrange it so that it is now on top of the task stack (ie: shown to the user). The existing instance of `A` is now underneath it.

In `B`, to go to `A`, modify the code with the same additional line to add the `REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag.

Keeping data in `EditText` is not a good or robust "persistency" solution, but for simple applications it can certainly be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't call finish when you start the other activity**. Then the original activity will stay in the activity stack and the data in the edit text will still be remain in the activity. Otherwise you should use **SharedPreferences** to store any temporary data you need to retain when you leave an activity. Then reload them using **SharedPreferences**.

or

```
public class A extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
     private Button nextBtn;
     private EditText editText;
     private String store;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.create_data);
         editText = findViewById(/*edit text id*/);
         nextBtn = findViewById(/*button id*/);
         nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         store = editText.getText().toString();

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case /*your button id*/:
        Intent c = new Intent(this, B.class);
        startActivity(c);

    }
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     editText.setText(store);

 }
}
```

Comment: So, do I have to save all the variables in an activity window manually writing the code? Isn't there another method or library to save all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Activity A:

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

private String activityBEditTextContent = null;
private static final int CALL_B = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

    EditText edA = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_a);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
            intent.putExtra("editTextBContent", activityBEditTextContent);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CALL_B);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CALL_B && resultCode == ActivityB.SUCCESS) {
        activityBEditTextContent = data.getStringExtra("editTextBContent");
    }
}
}
```

Activity B:

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private EditText etB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    etB = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_b);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null) {
        String previousEditTextBValue = bundle.getString("editTextBContent", "");
        etB.setText(previousEditTextBValue);
    }

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_b);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityB.this.onBackPressed();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("editTextBContent", etB.getText().toString());
    setResult(SUCCESS, intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

In Activity A you should include any code required for long term storage of the contents of both `EditText`s.